# Can I re-construct the original JavaScript source file from a minified version and the corresponding source-map file?

Tags: javascript, node.js, minify, source-maps

I am working on a project where I have to statically analyse JavaScript code. However, for a few libraries, I only have access to a minified version of the file and the corresponding source-map. Is there a method/technique with which I can generate the original file using these files?

Comment: Why can't you statically analyze them in their minified state?

Comment: I can analyse the code. But I need to retrieve the names of the properties of a few objects.

Comment: minifiers generally don't mess with property names of objects unless they're extremely aggressive as it's difficult to analyze how they're being used.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I found a node.js library that can help do this: [Maximize](https://npmjs.org/package/maximize)
Corresponding [github repo](https://github.com/txase/maximize)

Comment: have you use it? If so did you find any traps for new players?

Comment: It works well. Although, it expects the input as a URL. You would have to make changes to input a file.

Comment: I **don't know Node JS** but I rewrote Maximize to work with local files (and actually work at all). Maybe someone who knows node-js would like to make this not horrible: https://github.com/timmc/unsourcemap

Answer (score 6):

If your objective is "just" to do a onetime re-construction of the original source code I did it using:

[Online Source Visualization](http://sokra.github.io/source-map-visualization/)

1. use the "Custom" option
2. upload compiled file
3. upload source map file

Depending on filesize it may take a while to view the results.

The correspoding Repo is [here](https://github.com/sokra/source-map-visualization/)

Answer (score 1):

This command line tool is really easy to use

npx uglify-js ugly.js -b --source-map "filename='ugly.js.map'" -o beauty.js

https://www.npmjs.com/package/uglify-js

https://stackoverflow.com/a/70584632/13581139