# can i deobfuscate js files if i have the map files realated to them?

Tags: javascript

So There is that old website i found and i wanted to clone it some how i got the source code for it, HTML-JavaScript-CSS simple website, so the source code contained JavaScript files that can't be read and map files related to it also hard to be read for a starter, i mean sorry i am not into coding but i can make edits to codes if it's understandable, but these JavaScript files were like only variables and the map file is to complicated to understand, if anybody can tell me the process because it's been hours trying to find a solution, thanks , if this question isn't good to be here i will delete it just write in the comment i like Stack Overflow and i don't want to get bad vibes thanks again.

Comment: Did you search for "unminify javascript"?

Comment: no sorry not familiar with that thanks i will try it now

Comment: @phuzi i think i might be found what i looked for through your keyword unminify here is it https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29463252/deobfuscation-of-minified-js-with-source-maps