# Unuglify js file with a source map

Tags: javascript

I am new to **JavaScript** and came across this practice of minimizing **javascript** files. I however couldn't find any tool Online or in VS code which could maximize my js code using an attached source file.

Here are the files that I have
a.js:

```
webpackJsonp([1],{681:function(... One line code
//# sourceMappingURL=a.js.map
```

a.js.map:

```
{"version":3,"file":"a.js",...
```

Which Online or VS Code tool can I use to unuglify my code?

Background:
I've tried `uglify-js` in the terminal

```
loc/to/uglifyjs/binary a.js -b --source-map a.js.map -o a_unuglified.js
```

I  got an error saying `a.js.map` is not a supported map. I've also tried using VS code plugins but none of them seem to work.

**EDIT**
The following worked:
1) loc/to/uglifyjs/binary a.js -b -o a_unuglified.js --source-map "filename='a.js.map'"
2) Using developer tools as Jon suggested

However, the unuglified code still had unknown symbols and variable names. I looked around and realized that that it is equivalent to compressed binary code and that it would be near impossible to get the original code. That compelled me to look for the source code which I instantly found.

**TLDR**
Look for original source code if you have that option instead of trying to unuglyfy.

Comment: Maybe https://beautifier.io/ is something that can help unuglify?

Answer (score 3):

Just an update to this question, the `uglify-js` API changed a little. Currently, it'd be something like:

```
npx uglify-js ugly.js -b --source-map "filename='ugly.js.map'" -o beauty.js
```

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/javascript/reference#format.  So, if you can load your code into the Chrome browser, you can make a minified JS file readable via the Developer Tools, and copy/paste from there...

(Quick edit... In fact, take a look at https://stackoverflow.com/a/36554691/7696162, as I think that answers your question.)

Comment: How do I open the java script file in Google chrome to inspect the source? It opens as a text file if I open directly.

Comment: With the web page that uses a.js / a.js.map, or creating a simple HTML page referencing a.js (per the stackoverflow reference above), open this page in Chrome and then open up developer tools.